# k8s: android app frontend + nodejs backend - uploading more than 20mb photos

Tags: android, node.js, okhttp

I need help with the next situation:

1. we have an k8s environment
2. we have an single instance of backend (nodejs faethers rest) and db (postgres)
3. as a frontend we have an android app

And we faced with not possible upload photos via android app more than 20mb, for-example max possible to upload is 10 photos, and the size is 23mb - k8s nginx ingress is returned 502 upstream close connection.

If we try to do the same thing (upload more than 20MB) bypassing our mobile app, using postman and connecting directly to the backend, everything is going great for us.

Here is ingress annotations in my terraform:

```
...
    annotations = {
      "cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer" = "letsencrypt"
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class"    = "nginx"
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.provider" = "nginx"

      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size"         = "0"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering"         = "off"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout"      = "900"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-request-buffering" = "off"
    }
...
```

I tried adding all sorts of parameters to annotations yesterday, starting from "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout", "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout number" and "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout" ending "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-timeout" and etc. I played with the parameters that seemed very close to me to solve our problem, but still, we get an error through the android application. :(

I am inclined to believe that something is wrongly implemented in our mobile application, but I am completely unsure about this.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I started an upload server on k8s, configured the ingress proxy with the annotations you provided and I didn't experience any issues. 20MB file got successfully uploaded. This makes me think that the issue is most probably sth else. But since I don't know anything about your server/application this is all I can do.

Comment: How did you upload the data to the server? Using an Android app?

Comment: I repeat, the main problem we encountered is uploading files over 20 mb, we get an upstream connection closed on ingress 502, if we connect bypassing our application, then everything upload as expected, the main problem we have with our android frontend application.

Comment: Here is ingress log:

2021/02/11 12:13:46 [error] 125#125: *134597 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: api.stage.name.name.org, request: "POST /posts HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80/posts", host: "api.stage.name.name.org"

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - is an IP addresses

Comment: My android developer uses okhttp on the side of his app, today we tried using Apache HttpClient instead of okhttp to test our problem. And all is succeeded, with this client the application works fine and uploads everything completely without errors. Probably the problem is okhttp, I want to create a issue in okhttp gitlab project. And will wait for any comments 'bout this.

Comment: If you want to create a bug in OkHttp GitHub project, please make sure it is reproducible or provide a test server.  But if it just ends up in the server returning a 502 Bad Gateway we can't help with the server problem.

Comment: Okay, how can we continue to communicate? I mean, we can probably provide a test endpoint with our server for you.